# Is there a setting or other way of getting the entire solution to build whenever I run a test?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there are a way of building the entire solution when I run or debug a test? My project retrieves files from .dll files to work, and not using project references. The tests would only build projects it is referenced to, because they aren't being referenced from the Unit Test project, they wouldn't be built/updated when it comes to running the tests, therefore I would get incorrect results.

Currently I have been rebuilding the entire solution before I run any tests, this is fine, but sometimes I forget and It would just make my life that extra bit easier if the solution was to rebuild when I run any test.

I am using MSTest in Visual 2015.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stop using dll references for in-solution-dependencies.

Comment: And no, there is no such feature.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is using a build event (right click on a project that is being built by running your tests > Properties > Build Events) and rebuild the projects you want (or the entire solution) with the command line, i.e.

```
msbuild.exe ProjectPath.csproj /t:Rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of the *Solution*, there is (under "Common Properties") a "Project Dependencies" tab.

Here you can set extra dependencies for your various projects, such as your unittest project. I guess that will cause those dependencies to be built first.

Answer (score -1):

There is an option that does the oposite.

Check this option and it will run all tests after you build:
[image]

If you "Exclude from project" the tests that you don't want to run, you can simply press F6 (to build) and you will build and run your tests in one shot.